# How do i prevent the Side Navigation to go back when i click on a link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sidenav

How do i prevent the Side Navigation to go back when i click on a link with javascript? Inside the Side Navigation i have Three links some page that are linked to  other pages .So whenever i open the Navigation and click the links the side navigation closes. how can i make it to navigate trough the pages but still keep the side nav open ?
mu javascript code is :

```
    var btn=document.getElementById("btn");


btn.onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("left").classList.add("activeL");
};
```

normally i use the add class in  javascript  and its only for opening !
i know its maybe a silly question ,but i'm a newcomer in Javascript and thank you in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

you could use a query string.  so your link could be:

```
<a href="example.com?navopen=open">my link</a>
```

Js would go something like this:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let myParam = urlParams.get('navopen');

if (myParam === "open") {
 //add whatever class/code makes the nav open, guessing:
 document.getElementById("left").classList.add("activeL");
}
```

I could be more specific if you add more of your markup/code
Hope this helps.

Comment: HTML

<body>

<div id="cont"> 

<button id="btn">menu</div>

<div id="left">



<a href="index.html">link1</a>

<a href="home.html">link2</a>



</div>

</div>

</body>



now for my css:

#btn{

position:fixed;

top:0px;

right:0px;

width:40px;

height40px;

background: red;

z-index:500;

};

#left{

position:fixed;

top:0px;

left:0px;

width:0%;

height:100%;

};

.activeL{

width:40%;

};      Now when i click on the links the nav closes , and i want to prevent that